# MySQL LOAD DATA - Can Footer Lines Be Ignored?

Tags: mysql

Can footer lines be ignored in a csv file using `LOAD DATA INFILE`?
I have used `IGNORE 1 LINES` to ignore header row. Is there some similar functionality to denote a marker for the end of the data payload in the csv file?

**Example load data script**

```sql
load data infile '/data/data.csv'
into table Staging
fields terminated by ',' enclosed by ''
lines terminated by '\r\n'
ignore 1 LINES
(col1,col2,col3)
set col0ID=null;
```

**Example file**

```
,col1,col2,col3
,2101,val2,val3
,2202,val3,val4
<some more data>
,,,,Count: n
,,,,Another Count: n
```

In the example above, is there some way to denote `,,,,Count: n` as the end of the data payload?

Comment: No built-in possibility. But you may use, for example, a trigger which detects such line and generates SIGNAL 45000. The lines already loaded stays loaded but the loading itself stops. Or maybe some CHECK constraint will do this.

Comment: Cheers thanks that should do the trick. If you want to propose your suggestion as answer then I will accept it. Thanks, appreciated :)

Comment: This is described in the documentation, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html#load-data-error-handling , and I do not see the reason for to post a copy of the documentation article as an answer.